# How to create a CountUp between two numbers with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to create a countup between two numbers with Jquery with intervals 15 and slowdown similar to the GIF image below?

[image]
I can't reproduce this effect.

```js
$('.count').each(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  jQuery({ Counter: 1243234 }).animate({ Counter: $this.attr('data-stop') }, {
    useGrouping: true,
    separator: ".",
    decimal: ",",
    speed: 99999,
    duration: 9999999,
    refreshInterval: 300,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function (now) {
      $this.text(Math.ceil(now));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span class="count" data-stop="3256986">3256986</span> Total downloads <br>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit, please? You want to count from number A to number B, updating the on-screen number every 15 (seconds? ms?). What do you mean by "with slowdown"?

Comment: Or: you want to count up every 15?  1, 16, 31, 46 ?

Comment: Note: if you use anything other than `linear` easing, the speed your numbers increase will change over time - eg your snippet starts slow then speeds up (swing).

Comment: @Sampson I want to update the count between the two numbers (1,243,234 at 3,256,986) with intervals of 15 and with the same speed as the GIF image.

Comment: @freedoomn-m Yes that's right

Comment: The `duration` just defines the total duration of the animation. There is no option to give it a 15s delay between each tick. I'd recommend making your own countup timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) solution using `.data` to store the current value and setTimeout to loop.  Change the timeout (150 here) to adjust the speed.  Same concepts can be used for a non-jquery solution.

Storing the current value in the element's data means:

- stored as an int, so no need to parse the text
- function can be used for multiple elements without them interfering (if you used global variables, this would be an issue)

```js
$("[data-stop]").each(function() {
    countCounter(this);
})

function countCounter(element) {
   var $this = $(element);
   var counter = $this.data("current") || ($this.text()*1);
   var stop = $this.data("stop");
   //console.log(counter, stop)
   counter += 15;
   if (counter > stop) counter = stop;
   
   $this.text(counter.toLocaleString())
   $this.data("current", counter)
   
   if (counter < stop)
        setTimeout(() => countCounter(element), 150);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="count" data-stop="3256986">3256700</span> Total downloads
<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

To replicate what you have in the GIF, you could create a simple 1-second interval that changes the value of an element's textContent property. Below is a simple approach. You should update it to make sure the start value and end value are valid, etc.

```js
// Specify a selector, start/end numbers, and increment size
graduallyIncrement(".number", 1234, 1498, 15);

function graduallyIncrement ( selector, start, end, incrementBy ) {

    // Start with an initial value, and an element reference
    let currentValue = start;
    let element = document.querySelector(selector);
  
    // Update our element to show our initial value
    element.textContent = currentValue.toLocaleString();
  
    // Create an interval to run every 1 second
    let interval = setInterval(() => {

        // Determine next number. This may be our current
        // number + 15, or it may be the end number.
        let nextNumber = Math.min(end, currentValue += incrementBy);
    
        // Update our element to show the new number
        element.textContent = nextNumber.toLocaleString();
    
        // Determine whether or not to stop updating
        if ( nextNumber === end ) {
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
  
    }, 1000);

}
```

```html
<div class="number">1,243,234</div>
```

Other ways to improve would be to make this a Promise, which *resolves* when the final number is met. Or pass it a callback function which can be called once the process is complete. Here's how you could use Promises to determine when the counting has completed:

```js
graduallyIncrement(".number", 1234, 1498, 15).then(() => {
    alert("Done counting!");
});

async function graduallyIncrement(selector, current, end, incrementBy) {

    // Start with an initial value, and an element reference
    let element = document.querySelector(selector);

    // Update our element to show our initial value
    element.textContent = current.toLocaleString();

    return new Promise(resolve => {

        // Create an interval to run every 1 second
        let interval = setInterval(() => {

            // Determine next number. This may be our current
            // number + 15, or it may be the end number.
            current = Math.min(end, current += incrementBy);

            // Update our element to show the new number
            element.textContent = current.toLocaleString();

            // Using a setTimeout lets the textContent update
            // complete before we show our ALERT
            setTimeout(() => {
                // Determine whether or not to stop updating
                if (current === end) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    resolve();
                }
            }, 0);

        }, 1000);

    });

}
```

Comment: Was this answer created with help from ChatGPT?

Comment: No, I wrote this solution on JSFiddle. Why?

Comment: I asked because you’d indicated that two of your other answers which you posted on the same day were generated via ChatGPT.

Comment: Both of those were identified up-front (prior to the answer itself) as being from ChatGPT, and marked as Community Wiki to avoid any reputation gain. And they were promptly deleted, by myself, shortly after learning of the community guideline against all ChatGPT-derived contributions.